# What is generally the best way to combine tabular image metadata with image data in a convolutional neural network?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I have 26 features from tabular data (clinical variables from patients like age gender etc) that I want to add to my cnn which is using xray images from patients. I am using the inception network. Right now I am just concatenating these features to the final fully connected layer just before the softmax activation.

My concern though is that since this final layer also contains 2048 image features that these 26 features will not contribute much in the classification.

Empirically, these 26 features should contribute more than the 2048 image features. A random forest trained on only 26 features did better than the cnn using only the images. I'd like to get a model that does better than either of them separately so I thought I should add these metadata features to the cnn.

Are my concerns warranted? What is the best approach?